# Java Swing draws rectangle not as intended?

Tags: java, swing

I tried to place some rectangles in the center. But it's not drawing at the right position. My code:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Canvas extends JPanel {
    
    Player player = new Player(this);
    
    public Canvas() {
        //setBackground(Color.blue);
        setBounds(270, 0, 1230, 1000);
        setLayout(null);
    }
    
    public void start() {
        int FPS = 60;
        double drawIinterval = 1000000000/FPS;
        double delta = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long currentTime;
        long timer = 0;
        int drawCount = 0;
        while(true) {
            
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            
            delta += (currentTime -lastTime) / drawIinterval;
            timer += (currentTime -lastTime);
            lastTime = currentTime;
            
            if(delta >= 1) {
                update();
                repaint();
                delta--;
                drawCount++;
            }
            
            if(timer >= 1000000000) {
                System.out.println("FPS: " + drawCount);
                drawCount = 0;
                timer = 0;
            }
            
        }
    }
    
      private void update() {
        
          player.update();
        
    }

    @Override
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            
            player.draw(g2);
            
            g2.drawRect(size().width/2 - 100/2 ,size().height/2 - 100/2, 100, 100);
      }
}
```

I also tried to place it next to the right border

```
g2.drawRect(size().width - 100 ,size().height - 100, 100, 100);
```

but that placed it inside the border. Just placing it on the left or top side worked. Any explanation for that?

Edit:
When trying to draw a line through the whole panel

```
g2.drawLine(0, 0, size().width, size().height);
```

it doesn't reach the bottom corner and just enters about 20 pixels before the bottom.

Main class:

```
class Main extends JFrame{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    

    
    
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(1500, 1000);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(canvas);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    
    canvas.start();
}
```

}

Comment: Don’t call deprecated methods like `size()`.  They are deprecated for a reason.  You should obtain the width with `getWidth()` and the height with `getHeight()`, as John is doing.  If you’re not sure which methods are deprecated, enable all compiler warnings, and then the compiler will tell you.

Comment: I'm using two panels. One is a sidebar and the second is the one I posted here. When setting the background color, I could see 2 different panels.... Also does "drawRect" draw a rectangle not a line, so I think in theory its right.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your line isn't going to the corner must have something to do with the Window you are displaying your canvas in. I modified your code so it could render the line and this is what I came out with. The line does go all the way to the corner.

[image]

Here's my version of your code.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Canvas extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Canvas()
    {
        setBackground(Color.blue);
        setForeground(Color.white);
        setBounds(270, 0, 1230, 1000);
        setLayout(null);
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

//      g2.drawRect(size().width / 2 - 100 / 2, size().height / 2 - 100 / 2, 100, 100);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        g2.drawLine(0, 0, size().width, size().height);
}

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

You can draw a rectangle around you canvas in paintComponent to prove this idea.

```
    g2.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
```

A real simple way to help you figure out what is taking up the extra space is to add system outs or logging to the paintComponent

```
        System.out.println(this);
```

In my example it shows me the visibleRect as I resize the canvas.

```
Canvas[,0,0,468x412,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=11,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
Canvas[,0,0,468x411,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=11,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
Canvas[,0,0,468x410,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=11,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
Canvas[,0,0,469x410,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=11,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
...
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the quick response. I tried to outprint the size and got the "right" values. But when I added your line of code : " g2.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);" it just painted visually the top and left line, the bottom and right side didnt show a line. Maybe my Main class is the source for the bug?!  I added it to the question.

Comment: I just realised that the problem might just be that I forgot to add the size of the window top border(the grey part)?! If so, how would I use that?

Comment: Please give a code full working sample and I might be able to help more. Here's some advice on how to do that  - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I dont understand. I edited the question and added the Main class which should fill the part you missed?!

Comment: Good suggestion re the MRE, and a tip: `[mre]` in a comment automatically turns into [mre]. OP: Note that this *answer* is in the form of an (excellent, BTW) MRE. A single copy/paste from the answer to the IDE. It compiles cleanly and runs. I considered adding together all those different code bits in the question to see the problem, but I really couldn't be bothered. [IMO] It's up to the person asking the question to make it ***easy*** for others to help.

Comment: OK I see the Main() now. The edits just seem to pop in and I don't see a notification. I would try out the BorderLayer like I used. The setLayout(null) makes me uncomfortable. I'll come back to this next week if it's not closed.